# Node js how to have leading period path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, cross-platform

I have a path to run e.g: `./abc/def/myshell.sh`

I use path.join like this

```
path.join('.', 'abc', 'def', 'myshell.sh');
```

but it removes the leading period.
How can I keep it? Is there any other function?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on whether you want the current working directory or the directory the script is is, you should use [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) or [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) as the first parameter to `path.join`.

I ran across the same issue [setting up a gulp build](https://github.com/ssube/web-template/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L12), where I needed to include a file from the script's directory. Using `path.join` seems to optimize out certain path segments, so `./` is discarded even if it's the first part of the path (and would be significant).

To avoid that, anything that provides an absolute path (cwd or dirname) can be passed instead, forcing a full path to be built.